# Skip a Trigger for a Specific User in Informix

Tags: informix, database-trigger

Is it possible to bypass a trigger when a specific db user is making changes by running a script?

In the when clause of a trigger in Informix, could we do this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    update on table_name
    referencing old as olddata new as newdata
    for each row when(USER <> 'a specific database user')
    (…triggered actions…)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Informix 12.10 on [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0584.htm) eventually leads to the [WHEN condition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0619.htm) description.

As long as you can predict when the trigger is created which user(s) should not trigger the action, you should be able to write something like `WHEN (USER != 'exempt')`, but it would be harder to make it work dynamically.  You might be able to invoke a stored procedure in the WHEN condition that evaluates whether the current user is currently exempt from triggering the action.  It probably can't be done meaningfully other than by using a stored procedure either in the WHEN condition or as the triggered action.

#### Proof of concept

**Schema and trigger**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trigger_test;
CREATE TABLE trigger_test
(
    s   SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    t   DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND,
    v   VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trigger_log;
CREATE TABLE trigger_log
(
    log_id  SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    old_s   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    old_t   DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    new_t   DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    old_v   VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    new_v   VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    log_t   DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND,
    log_u   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT USER
);

CREATE TRIGGER skip_user
    UPDATE ON trigger_test
    REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW WHEN(USER != 'informix')
    (INSERT INTO trigger_log(old_s, old_t, new_t, old_v, new_v)
        VALUES(old.s, old.t, new.t, old.v, new.v)
    )
    ;
```

**Sequence of operations as non-informix user**

I'm using my `sqlcmd` program (available from the [IIUG Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software) in the ESQL section — it's quite distinct from Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program with the same name) and a custom tool `a6` which switches to use `informix` credentials (effectively like `su informix` or `sudo informix`).

```
$ sqlcmd -d stores -xHTf user-action.sql 
+ INSERT INTO trigger_test(v) VALUES("Hello");
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_test;
s|t|v
SERIAL|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)
1|2019-12-19 17:04:04|Hello
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_log;
log_id|old_s|old_t|new_t|old_v|new_v|log_t|log_u
SERIAL|INTEGER|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)|VARCHAR(64)|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(32)
+ UPDATE trigger_test SET t = '2019-12-31 23:59:59', v = 'Farewell to 2019';
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_test;
s|t|v
SERIAL|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)
1|2019-12-31 23:59:59|Farewell to 2019
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_log;
log_id|old_s|old_t|new_t|old_v|new_v|log_t|log_u
SERIAL|INTEGER|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)|VARCHAR(64)|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(32)
1|1|2019-12-19 17:04:04|2019-12-31 23:59:59|Hello|Farewell to 2019|2019-12-19 17:04:04|jonathanleffler
+ UPDATE trigger_test SET t = '2038-01-19 03:14:07', v = 'Farewell to 32-bit Unix time';
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_test;
s|t|v
SERIAL|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)
1|2038-01-19 03:14:07|Farewell to 32-bit Unix time
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_log;
log_id|old_s|old_t|new_t|old_v|new_v|log_t|log_u
SERIAL|INTEGER|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)|VARCHAR(64)|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(32)
1|1|2019-12-19 17:04:04|2019-12-31 23:59:59|Hello|Farewell to 2019|2019-12-19 17:04:04|jonathanleffler
2|1|2019-12-31 23:59:59|2038-01-19 03:14:07|Farewell to 2019|Farewell to 32-bit Unix time|2019-12-19 17:04:04|jonathanleffler
$
```

As you can see, the actions I took are logged in the `trigger_log` table.

**Sequence of actions as user informix**

```
$ a6 sqlcmd -d stores -xHTf ifmx-action.sql 
+ UPDATE trigger_test SET t = '2019-01-01 00:00:00', v = 'Welcome to the New Year 2019';
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_test;
s|t|v
SERIAL|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)
1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|Welcome to the New Year 2019
+ SELECT * FROM trigger_log;
log_id|old_s|old_t|new_t|old_v|new_v|log_t|log_u
SERIAL|INTEGER|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(64)|VARCHAR(64)|DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND|VARCHAR(32)
1|1|2019-12-19 17:04:04|2019-12-31 23:59:59|Hello|Farewell to 2019|2019-12-19 17:04:04|jonathanleffler
2|1|2019-12-31 23:59:59|2038-01-19 03:14:07|Farewell to 2019|Farewell to 32-bit Unix time|2019-12-19 17:04:04|jonathanleffler
$
```

As you can see, the update took effect, but the result was not recorded in the `trigger_log` table.

As you might also observe, the UPDATE statements used are sloppy; they update all rows.  It might be better to use DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5) too.  My database servers run with their time zone set to UTC — the insert times are therefore recorded in UTC too.